# Decorator for many properties in Python

Tags: python, decorator

Is it possible to write a decorator that creates many properties at once?

Like instead of writing

```
class Test:
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.ref.a
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.ref.b
```

I'd like to write

```
class Test:
    @properties("a", "b")
    def prop(self, name):
        return getattr(self.ref, name)
```

Is it possible? Do you recommend it?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but there are almost certainly better solutions.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why are you using properties over standard attributes here in the first place?

Comment: Note that the code in the class `Test` leads to infinite recursion.  Could you please fix it to give us a clearer idea of your intentions?

Comment: Maybe replace the self.a and self.b by self._a and self._b ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to show that I actually want to forward a particular set of properties to another object. Changed now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that a decorator

```
@decorator(dec_args)
def foo(args):
    pass
```

is just syntactic sugar for writing

```
def foo(args):
    pass
foo = decorator(dec_args)(foo)
```

So it is not possible for a method decorator to result in more than one method (or property, etc.) to be added to a class.

An alternative might be a class decorator that injects the properties:

```
def multi_property(prop, *names):
    def inner(cls):
        for name in names:
            setattr(cls, name, property(lambda self, name=name: prop(self, name)))
    return inner

@multi_property(prop, 'a', 'b')
class Test:
    pass
```

However it'd usually be clearer to have each property present within the body of the class:

```
a = forward_property('ref', 'a')
b = forward_property('ref', 'b')
```

where `forward_property` returns a property object as appropriate implementing the descriptor protocol.  This is friendlier to documentation and other static analysis tools, as well as (usually) the reader.

Comment: What's the hack closest to what I intend? A class decorator?

Comment: @Gerenuk yes, but please consider the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way of writing a proxy for another object is to implement `__getattr__()`:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, ref1, ref2):
        self._ref1 = ref1
        self._ref2 = ref2
    def __getatrr__(self, name):
        if name in ["a", "b", "c"]:
            return getattr(self._ref1, name)
        if name in ["d", "e", "f"]:
            return getattr(self._ref2, name)
```

Note that `__getattr__()` is only called for attributes that are not found in the current instance, so you can also add further methods and attributes to `Proxy`.

Comment: It's no a pure proxy. And also I might send requests to different reference objects. But I suppose only `__getattr__` can be a solution or is there a neat combination?

Comment: @Gerenuk: I extended the example a bit.

Comment: That's the solution I was just about to take for my script... It certainly answers the question. Then I saw acatmur's proposal and it seems cleaner even though, it's not as short as I asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

One provision in the lagnuage for what you probably really intend is writting the  `__setattr__` method for a class.

This method is caleed whenever an attribute that normally does not exist is is acessed on the instance:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...    a = 0
...    def __getattr__(self, attr):
...       return attr
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.a
0
>>> t.b
'b'
>>> t.c
'c'
```

What you are directly asking is also possible, bute requires some hacks - that although not advisable by common sense, are widely used in production in the wild. 
Namely, for a property to exist in Python, it is a class attribute ound to a special type of object - one that has at least the `__get__` method. (to learn more check about the "Descriptor Protocol" on Python docs).

Now, trying to create several properties at once, like the code you pasted by example, would require that the property names would be injected in the class name space from the called function. It _ is possible_, and even *used in production* in Python, and not evenhard to achieve. But not pretty, nonetheless.

So, a possible way of avoiding this is to have a call that returns a sequence of "property" objects - that is clean, readable and maintanable:

```
class MultiProperty(object):
    def __init__(self, getter, setter, name):
        self.getter = getter
        self.setter = setter
        self.name = name
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.getter(instance, self.name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        return self.setter(instance, self.name, value)

def multi_property(mgetter, msetter, *args):
    props = []
    for name in args:
        props.append(MultiProperty(mgetter, msetter, name))
    return props


class Test(object):
    def multi_getter(self, attr_name):
        # isf desired, isnert some logic here
        return getattr(self, "_" + attr_name)

    def multi_setter(self, attr_name, value):
        # insert some logic here
        return setattr(self, "_" + attr_name, value)        
    a,b,c = multi_property(multi_getter, multi_setter, *"a b c".split())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible from within the class. However, you can modify the class afterwards. See here:

```
def makeprop(meth, name):
    # make a property calling the given method.
    # It is not really a method, but it gets called with the "self" first...
    return property(lambda self: meth(self, name))

def propfor(cls, *names):
    def wrap(meth):
        for name in names:
            # Create a property for a given object, in this case self,
            prop = makeprop(meth, name)
            setattr(cls, name, prop)
        return meth # unchanged
    return wrap

class O(object):
    # just a dummy for your ref
    a = 9
    b = 12
    c = 199

class C(object):
    ref = O()

# Put the wanted properties into the class afterwards:
@propfor(C, "a", "b", "c")
def prop(self, name):
    return getattr(self.ref, name)

# alternative approach with a class decorator:
def propdeco(*names):
    meth = names[-1]
    names = names[:-1]
    def classdeco(cls):
        propfor(cls, *names)(meth) # not nice, but reuses code above
        return cls
    return classdeco

@propdeco("a", "b", "c", lambda self, name: getattr(self.ref, name))
class D(object):
    ref = O()

print C().a
print C().b
print C().c

print D().a
print D().b
print D().c
```

If you prefer the 2nd approach, you should write `propdeco` as

```
def propdeco(*names):
    meth = names[-1]
    names = names[:-1]
    def classdeco(cls):
        for name in names:
            # Create a property for a given object, in this case self,
            prop = makeprop(meth, name)
            setattr(cls, name, prop)
        return cls
    return classdeco
```